# SQL string function QUOTENAME() not giving result for long strings

Tags: sql-server

`QuoteName(i.ItemDescription,CHAR(34))` is not giving any result when the item description is very long. Is there any solution that can let us hold the string longer than 128 characters and return it?

Comment: From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) - first argument _is sysname and is limited to 128 characters. Inputs greater than 128 characters return NULL_

Comment: Use `CONCAT('"', YourLongString, '"')`

Comment: @Sami you need to double up any embedded quotes with REPLACE too

Comment: @MartinSmith 
CONCAT('=', QuoteName(i.ItemDescription,CHAR(34))) AS ItemDescription.
Is there any solution to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with another way as

```
SELECT CONCAT('"', REPLACE(YourLongString, '"', '""'), '"')
```